# Calculate road lengths

Tags: distance, qgis-processing

I have two layers: one is a polygon and another one is a line (Road).
How can I find in how much road in falls inside each polygon?

Comment: You can intersect each other

Answer (score 1):

Clip the Road layer with Polygon Layer. Clip is located in

`Vector->Geoprocessing Tools->Clip`.